# Peewee Show item that appears most in ORM table (calculation)

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have two tables in my database:

Table 1: Users

```
userid   name   department
123      Sam    Management
124      Joe    Employee
```

Table 2: Activity

```
userid activity
123    login
123    browse
123    browse
123    browse
123    logout
124    signup
```

I would like to have 'Summary' table which can give me lots of information regarding these two tables

```
userid   name   department   activityCount   topActivity
123      Sam    Management   5               Browse
124      Joe    Employee     1               Signup
```

There are plenty of ways of getting these results, but what is there a right way?

I am using peewee, So to be more clear:

1) How can I count the number of events for a certain userId and add it as a value to a new table/column (Something similar to pandas `df.group_by(userid).count()`)

2) How can I get the most listed object for a userid and add it as a value to a new table/column

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to join the `users` table with an aggregate query that counts and ranks the activities per user:

```
select 
    u.userid,
    u.name,
    u.department,
    sum(activity_count) activity_count,
    max(case when a.rn = 1 then a.activity end) top_activity
from users u
inner join (
    select 
        activity, 
        userid, 
        count(*) activity_count ,
        row_number() over(partition by userid order by count(*) desc) rn
    from activity
    group by activity, userid
) a on a.userid = u.userid
group by u.userid, u.name, u.department
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cdebc3dbab06766f1263400084473a30)**:

```
userid | name | department | activity_count | top_activity
:----- | :--- | :--------- | :------------- | :-----------
123    | Sam  | Management | 5              | browse      
124    | Joe  | Employee   | 1              | signup
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I am required to write the code in Peewee. Do you know how? I appreciate the trouble. I am also trying now to put this into peewee language :)

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh: sorry, I have no knowledge in Peewee.

Comment: No stress, Thanks. I am sure I can translate this. You've given me much more than I had. Thanx man